Pressure washer doesnt start and leaking gas
I replaced the oil in my pressure washer which I didn't use for a year. I used the right oil from the manual, so it should not be an issue.
After that I tried to start it a few times. It didn't start but instead the gas started leaking really fast. Attaching the picture.
Any advice how to fix?


The float might need some cleaning/work.

The old gas in the carb turned into a sticky gum. This stuck the float in the carb in the down position, permanently opening the float valve, allowing new gas from the tank to fill the bowl and overflow it.
If the gas tank has a shut-off valve, shut it off. Otherwise, remove as much gas from the tank as possible.
Remove the fastener at the bottom of the carb bowl. This should allow the bowl to be removed. If it's stuck, tap it gently with a piece of wood or plastic.
Clean the inside of the bowl with spray carb cleaner. Also spray carb cleaner on the float and all moving parts that were formerly hidden by the bowl until everything moves freely. The float should move up and down about half an inch or 1 cm.
Reassemble, fuel up and see if it starts. If it does not (or if it runs poorly), the carb needs more extensive cleaning to unclog ports and passages. That's beyond the scope of this answer.

seems like it was leaking from the gasket. I opened it, and didn't see any sticky old gas, anything like that, all is clean. Assembled and tried to start again... when choke is on - it starts for 2 seconds and stops. any recommendations?

@Rainmaker (1) Assume you have the high pressure hose disconnected so you're not trying to start against a high load. (2) If it's warm / hot in your region, you can try half choke or no choke. (3) Sticky / stuck parts in carb or clogged passages. Moving parts in carb have to be able to move under influence of air flow. Even though you found no sticky gas, best to spray all moving parts while moving them full range. If still NG, search for procedures to clean carb passages. It may be less trouble to replace carb.

thanks. ordered a new carb. seems not expensive.

replacing carb fixed the issue!

@Rainmaker Good deal! Be safe.
